# Using git fast-export to export a repo starting at a given commit

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I am currently trying to merge the current repo at work with one that was converted from my work's old svn repo. I want the new repo (we'll call it A) to be merged with the current working repo (B).

B is the result of a failed attempt to convert the svn repo to git with the history intact. A is the second attempt. If I just merge B with A, there will be duplicate commits for everything in the old svn repo. I would like to only include the history from B that happened after the last svn commit.

I am looking at git-fast-export, but I haven't found any documentation that would help me. Should I use git-fast-export, or is there a better way? How would I use git-fast-export or something else to do the merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one branch to merge back, then another way would be to use grafts (see "[gardening tips -- grafting branches](http://gitolite.com/archived/grafting.html)"):

- Add `B` as a remote for `A`: "`remoteB`",
- find the SHA1 of `A` representing the SVN repo converted (and from which new commits were done): "`SHA1-A`",
- find the SHA1 of `B` representing the next commit *after* the SVN repo converted (that is, the first of the new commits done from the failed SVN conversion): "`SHA1-B`",
- See [this example](http://blog.agavi.org/post/16865375185/fixing-svn-merge-history-in-git-repositories):

> You can override parents of a commit in Git using a file called grafts, which needs to reside in `.git/info/`.
>   It consists of several lines with commit hashes separated by a space character, where the first hash is the commit you want to define parents for, and the following hashes are the parents.
>
> Note: you must use full hashes, not abbreviated ones.
>
> To fix the history above, we must define the parents in `.git/info/grafts`:

```
SHA1-B SHA1A
```

- Make that graft permanent:

  ```
  git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
  ```
- Make a local branch reference the HEAD of `B` branch you just grafte,.

  ```
  git branch Bmaster remoteB/master
  ```
- Merge your two branches (and you can remove the 'remoteB' repo, you don't need it anymore).